# Set Visibility of Parent Container

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to set the visibility of of my parent container by checking the visibility each of the Controls that it contains. If none of the controls that it contains are visible, then the parent container is hidden. I know how to do this by hard coding each and every one of the Controls that the container contains. However, I'd like to perform this checking without having to type out the name of each of the controls that the container contains in the code behind. Is there a way to do this in the code behind? I am not not looking for a multi-data trigger.

Comment: I'd expect you'd have to go into a long journey with that one if you aren't binding to their `IsVisible` property and doing logic against the results. You could walk all over the dependency tree if you want. This is a starting point: http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/02/find-wpf-parent . You can rework it to go in the other direction to find all children an aggregate visibility.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate thru child controls and set the visibility

**Winform version**

```
var isParentVisible = false;

foreach(Control child in ParentContainer.Controls)
{
   isParentVisible = child.IsVisible;

   if(isParentVisible)
      break;
}
```

**WPF version**

```
var isParentVisible = false;

foreach (var child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(ParentContainer)) 
{
  if (!(child is UIElement)) {
    continue;
  }

  isParentVisible = child.IsVisible;

  if(isParentVisible)
    break;
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, that only gets the first level children. If that works for you, great! But if not, you might have to use some recursion to iterate over all children's children too. If you're looking for an example, I wrote [this set of helper libraries](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/10/09/navigating-wpfs-visual-tree/) that might help get you started in the right direction. It's for finding Parent or Child objects of a specific type instead of checking for visibility, however the concept is the same.

Comment: You're correct! But I don't think the question had any talk of subchildren